# is there a way to process data in a sql table column before ingesting it to hbase using sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hbase, sqoop

data needs to be ingested from sql table to hbase using sqoop.i have xml data in one column. instead of ingesting the complete xml for each row, i want to required details from xml and then ingest it with rest of the columns. is there a way like writing UDF where xml column is passed and output is used along with other sql columns to ingest.

Comment: Sqoop doesn't really do UDF. Sounds like Spark might be more preferred

Answer (score 0):

No but you can extend the Java class PutTransformer (https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.4/SqoopDevGuide.html), add your XML transformation logic there, and pass the custom JAR file to the sqoop command.

Comment: harold i had one more q. i was trying to import entire xml in hbase. while reading the table as dataframe in spark, xm is coming correctly but few other columns are appearing null. it happens when xml size increases from a certain limit. below that it works fine.

Comment: @hansr no idea for that one, but Spark shall be avoided whenever there are some easy options